# geom_forecast in the forecast package

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wanted to replicate Rob Hyndman's ggplot2 graphics example using `geom_forecast()` in the `forecast` package; namely:

```
library(magrittr)

WWWusage %>% 
  auto.arima() %>% 
  forecast(level=c(50, 80, 95)) -> fc

autoplot(WWWusage) +
  geom_forecast(fc, color='#ffcccc', show.legend=FALSE) +
  labs(x="Minute", y="Number of users", "Forecasts from ARIMA model")
```

Changing the `show.legend` option to `show.legend=TRUE` does not reveal the legend. Is there a bug here?

Comment: You have a single series in a `Time-Series` object. The `lungDeaths` example in `geom_forecast()` has two in an `mts` object. What are you expecting to be in this legend you desire?

Comment: Ah, you meant the full example [from his slides](http://wombat2016.org/slides/rob.pdf). I would classify this as a bug & file an issue.

Comment: @ hrbmstr yes, it's from his slides. I'm expecting the prediction interval colors for 50, 80 and 95 to be itemised in the label. I ran an example with a data frame at this end on obtained a legend, by default. Is this not possible for a Time-series object?

Comment: Right. I tried the examples in Rob's slides that I linked to and got similar results. IMO it's a bug that shld be noted. ggfortify has a fortify for time series objects that seems a bit more mature and sane. Might want to try that. geom_forecast() seems to lack robustness, but it's also the first version of it.

Comment: Thanks. There also seems to be a conflict with ggfortify  - look here https://github.com/sinhrks/ggfortify/issues/106. Still, let's be grateful that Rob Hyndman has linked his forecast package to ggplot2 - it will come good in the end.

Comment: Oh, no criticism intended of the newfound support for a sane plotting idiom :-)